# Android XML The id "listView" is not defined anywhere

Tags: java, android, xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.app.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listOfLists"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/listView1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/listView1"
    android:onClick="NewListActivity"
    android:text="New List v2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/listView1"
    android:text="Receipts"
    android:onClick="ReceiptsActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I get an error saying

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - The id "listView" is not defined anywhere. Did you mean one of {listView1, listView2} ?
    - error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_alignEnd' with value '@id/
```

I'm not using listView, i'm using listView1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
android:layout_alignEnd="@id/listView1"
```

to

```
android:layout_alignEnd="@id/listOfLists"
```

coz you have

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/listOfLists"
```

Similarly replace in other places with `@+id/listOfLists`

Edit:

Use

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.app.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listOfLists"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/listOfLists"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/listOfLists"
    android:onClick="NewListActivity"
    android:text="New List v2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/listOfLists"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/listOfLists"
    android:text="Receipts"
    android:onClick="ReceiptsActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply however, even after changing it it's the same error. The instance of 'listOfLists' was actually called listView1 and I was still getting the error, I changed them all to match listOfLists and it still isn't working.

Comment: Thank you my friend! I'm 40 minutes late in submitting my coursework because of this problem and you fixed it in a couple of minutes!